# Extraction of characters from forms with boxed field inputs

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, form-processing

I am trying to extract characters from all fields in forms with boxes such as the one shown here:

Sample printed form

[image: Sample printed form]

My current approach is as follows:

1. Crop the field from the form based on some standard format.
2. Image pre-processing and finding contours around the boxes of fields.
3. Based on the number of boxes in that field, crop each small box and run character recognition on these cropped character images.

The boxes may be slightly tilted in the images. I use an alignment algorithm but it still does not always straighten the box edges. This can be seen in this image:

Aligned date crop

[image: Aligned date crop].

On such images, when I crop characters using straight lines (step 3 of the algorithm mentioned above), the edges of boxes are also included which confuse the character recognition module. For example, the number '3' and 'the box edge' is represented as 31 sometimes.

I want to use pre-trained models only and hence, I am looking for a better way to extract characters from the boxed fields properly.

I would highly appreciate any help provided by the SO community.

Comment: Hi @chintan, have you found the solution of your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the box edges are generally thinner (as in your case) than the text inside them, we can leverage this information.
By applying a horizontal morphological closing kernel (Dilation -> Erosion), we can make thin vertical lines white, which will help OCR. Some trash may be left after processing but that wouldn't hinder OCR accuracy. The size of the kernel depends on the width of the border lines. Obviously, you can tweak it as per your case.

Here is the sample code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
im = cv2.imread('sample_image.png')
im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

k1 = (4,1)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, k1)
im = cv2.morphologyEx(im, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1)

_,im = cv2.threshold(im, thresh=200, maxval=255, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imwrite('sample_output.png',im)
```

And here are the images:

1. sample_image.png
   [image]
2. sample_output.png
   [image]